# how can I disable tabs in Avalon Dock from Extended WPF Toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I was going through an example a while back and set up properties to bind to visibility and other porperties on the LayoutItem. I am able to set them to visibile or not but now I want to disable the tabs. I had a binding to IsEnabled in my style, but now I don't see the property in the LayoutItem class. So I am thinking I may of added it during exploration of the ToolKit. But now I am using the Nuget package found online and I can not figure out a way to disable the tab of the panel. Any ideas, of a way to disable my tabs?

```
                <templateselectors:PanesStyleSelector>
                    <templateselectors:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                            <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}"/>
                            <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
                            <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}"/>
                            <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="{Binding Model.IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Model.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
                        </Style>
                    </templateselectors:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
                </templateselectors:PanesStyleSelector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it out in my set of mods for the Avalon Dock. Added the following snippet to my own AvalonDock Theme, and it allows to disable individual tabs.

For the demonstration I used the `IsSelected` Property of LayoutDocument, since there is of course no `IsEnabled`.

```
<Style x:Key="DocumentPaneControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```